# duplicate association path exception with CreateAlias

Tags: hibernate, grails

I've been stuck on this the whole day (yesterday)! i appreciate any help or tips !

Im trying to use createAlias inside createCriteria to sort a list of object ( to handle null values) !the list is created using createCriteria.

the exception thrown only when using createAlias for a specific  not-nullable property (class) of the object!
 i used createAlias for other properties (classes ) of the object i list and it works !

Here is my code !

```
someClass.createCriteria().list(){
class1{ 
eq("sth",sth)
}

    if (sort == 'sth.else') {
    createAlias("class1", "s1", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)

    order("s1.name", sortOrder)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
someClass.createCriteria().list(){
    createAlias("class1", "s1", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    s1 { 
        eq("sth",sth)
    }

    if (sort == 'sth.else') {
        order("s1.name", sortOrder)
    }
}
```